# Return an array of (edited) matched items of two other arrays and (unedited) non-matched items

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

## My goal

I'm trying to link rows in two different sheets in the same spreadsheet according to a value in a cell. The basic idea is that if a value in column B in Sheet1 has a matched value in column B in Sheet2, an hyperlink should be added to the cell with the matched value in Sheet1 linking to the whole row of the matched value in the Sheet2.

#### What I did

As you can see from the code below, it looks for the matches, if it's found, it edits the matched values to add the hyperlinks. I don't only want to push the "linked" matched values into the new array, I also want the non-matched values without the link. The idea is that the link will be added if a match is found, otherwise the value will still be added, just without the link.

```
function linkToContacts(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var Sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var Sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    var Sheet2ID = Sheet2.getSheetId();

    var arrSheet1 = Sheet1.getRange(4,2,Sheet1.getLastRow()-3).getValues(); // -3 because I have 3 row as headers before the data, which start in row 4 col B
    var arrSheet2 = Sheet2.getRange(4,2,Sheet2.getLastRow()-3).getValues(); // -3 because I have 3 row as headers before the data, which start in row 4 col B

    var arrOutput = [];

    for(var i = 0; i<arrSheet1.length;i++){
      for(var j = 0; j<arrSheet2.length;j++) {
        if(arrSheet1[i][0] === arrSheet2[j][0]){
          arrOutput.push(['=HYPERLINK("#gid=' + Sheet2ID + '&range=' + Sheet2.getRange(j+4,2,1,Sheet2.getLastColumn()-1).getA1Notation() + '";"' + arrSheet1[i][0] + '")']);
        } else {
          arrOutput.push([arrSheet1[i][0]]);
        }
      }
    }

    Sheet1.getRange(4,2,Sheet1.getLastRow()).clearContent();
    Sheet1.getRange(4,2,arrOutput.length).setValues(arrOutput);
  }
```

#### The problem

**The two arrays contain only unique values respectively**. The problem is that, because of the double loop, each item is checked by the length of arrSheet2. So for instance let's imagine this scenario:

```
var arrSheet1 = [apple,avocado,banana];
var arrSheet2 = [apple,banana,mango,];
```

the `arrOutput` will result in:

```
arrOutput = [
          apple(link),apple,apple,
          avocado,avocado,avocado,
          banana(link),banana,banana
];
```

In a quick, probably unelegant, way to solve the issue I've tried to delete the duplicates frm `arrOutput` but obviously the value with the link and the values without are different so the best it can get with this solution is this:

```
arrOutput = [
          apple(link),apple,
          avocado,
          banana(link),banana
];
```

### Question

Is there a smarter/more efficient way to get to

```
arrOutput = [apple(link),avocado,banana(link)];
```

or in case what I'm doing actually makes sense, what I should do to get to the result above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

- Double looping and pushing array elements multiple times

#### Solution:

- Use `break` and conditional `if` statements to control logic

#### Flow:

- If hyperlink is pushed, break the second sheet loop
- Only push Sheet1 element if there's no hyperlinks in Sheet2(i.e., Wait till the last element of Sheet2 is iterated)

#### Snippet:

```
for(var i = 0; i<arrSheet1.length;i++){
  for(var j = 0, k = arrSheet2.length-1; j<=k; j++) {// modified
    if(arrSheet1[i][0] === arrSheet2[j][0]){
      arrOutput.push(['=HYPERLINK("#gid=' + Sheet2ID + '&range=' + Sheet2.getRange(j+4,2,1,Sheet2.getLastColumn()-1).getA1Notation() + '";"' + arrSheet1[i][0] + '")']);
      break; //break j loop to continue next i loop
    } else if(j === k){//push sheet1 only on the last element
      arrOutput.push([arrSheet1[i][0]]);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- Use of objects `{}` might be better. Convert sheet2 array to object `{val1:hash,val2:hash,...}`. Then you can easily check if sheet1 elements are present in sheet2 using `in`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to create a new array that contains only matching elements. If no elements are found this will return an empty array.

```
var arrSheet1 = ['apple','avocado','banana'];
var arrSheet2 = ['apple','banana','mango'];

var intersect = arrSheet1.filter(function (element) {
  return arrSheet2.includes(element);
});

// ['apple','banana']
```

Or without an [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) polyfill:

```
var intersect = arrSheet1.filter(function (element) {
  return arrSheet2.indexOf(element) !== -1);
})
```

Comment: Arrow functions are not yet supported in apps script

Comment: Thanks @TheMaster, updated to correspond with your comment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Cue but unfortunately this won't work since the result that I'm looking for is not an array of only matching elements. As I mentioned, the logic should be the followig: if an element is matched then a link is added to it (=HYPERLINK(elements)) and it is pushed in arrOutput, if there is no match then the element ALSO gets pushed in the array but without the transformation of the elements itself with the addition of the link. Hence, the resulting array I'm aiming for should be ['=HYPERLINK(apple)',avocado,'=HYPERLINK(banana)']. I hope it's more clear now! Thanks